# I want to make Rule msg dynamic VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js, mvvm, vuetify.js

```
<v-text-field :rules="[v => !!v || 'Name is required']" label="Name" v-model="crewDetailObj.name" ></v-text-field>
<v-text-field :rules="[v => !!v || 'Address is required']" label="Address" v-model="address" ></v-text-field>

validate(v,msg)
{
 return [v => !!v || '$msg is required']
}
```

is it possible to make rule msg to be dynamic that take value from label ?
    or a function that i pass a name and then in return in give me that rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible, you just have to return a function which return either a boolean or a string, which is your message.

here is an example:

```
<v-text-field
     :rules="[
     (value) => { return (genericRequiredRule(value, "myMessage")) }
     ]"
</v-text-field>
```

and here is the js mixins which i use to validate my fields:

```
genericRequiredRule: (value, msg) => !!value || msg
```

i hope it helped and andwered your questions.